# Проблема присваиванию двух одинаковых переменных

Tags: c, инициализация, оператор-присваивания

**Первый вариант:**

```
int max, min = nabc[0];
printf("Max: %d Min: %d", max, min);
```

result:

```
Max: 6422224 Min: 1 // Ответ "max" НЕ верный
```

**Второй вариант:**

```
int max, min;
max = min = nabc[0];
printf("Max: %d Min: %d", max, min);
```

result:

```
Max: 3 Min: 1 // Ответ верный
```

В чём проблема? Не могу понять, почему из-за перебора присваивания происходит такая ошибка?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Здесь

```
int max, min = nabc[0];
```

мы видим объявление *неинициализированной* переменной `max` и переменной `min`, инициализированной значением `nabc[0]`.

Здесь же

```
int max, min;
max = min = nabc[0];
```

мы видим объявление двух неинициализированных переменных `max` и `min` и присвоение им значения `nabc[0]`.

В С нет ни множественного присвоения, ни множественной инициализации через запятую.